# How can I make height: "100%" work cross browser in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 columns that are achieved by floating. They do not stretch to 100% when using css. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can't. I have tried forever to do this - there is no cross-browser way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on this and there is no way to do in it css intuitively. There are ways such as tricking the aesthetics by using an image behind the short column to repeat downwards.

Other way is using javascript, If i find those posts, i'll update this.

http://www.thechoppr.com/blog/2009/02/09/2-column-fluid-layout-100-height-with-leftright-sidebar/

Answer (score 1):

try setting the min-height on that columns and all all of their containing elements (including body and html) to 100%.  [see here](http://www.tutwow.com/tips/quick-tip-css-100-height/)

EDIT: I've heard that this won't work in ie8, but I've tested it and it looked ok,

Answer (score 0):

```
#columns {
    height:100%;
}
```

The problem with css and height is that it is not consistent across browsers. You would be better off not worrying about height. You also have the issue of different screen resolutions.

If height is really important I would tackle it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
    <script language="Javascript" src="http://i.ngen-io.us/core/js/b4dom.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript">
    var currHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("MyColumnDiv").style.height = ''.currHeight.'px';
    </script>
```

You can also set the width using this example. Feel free to reuse my library, but please note its source in your code.

Comment: I like this. I'm gonna use it too +1.

Comment: This isn't consistent across all browsers. See this SO answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers)

Comment: It is consistent if you use my library, otherwise no, it will not be consistent.

Comment: BTW: Tested on Firefox, Opera, MSIE 5+, Safari, Chrome and works perfectly across the board even on blackberry, iPhone and Ubuntu, Fedora & Redhat Linux (using Firefox).

Comment: the guy search CSS solution, not javascript solution

Answer (score 0):

To achieve 100% height using CSS you must make sure the enclosing block is also set to height: 100%; including the `<html>` element.

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

#YourBlock
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css & html, tested and works in FFx 3.5, IE 8 & Safari 4 - works partially in IE7 by applying a background color to #container.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#container  { width:800px; margin:25px auto; position:relative;display:block;overflow: hidden;}
#header     { height: 80px;background: #eee; }
#wrapper    { float:left;width:100%}
#col2       { margin:0 200px;background: #ddd; }
#col1       { float:left; width:200px; margin-left:-800px; background: #eee; }
#col3       { float:left; width:200px; margin-left:-200px; background: #ccc; }    
#col1, #col2, #col3 { padding-bottom:32767px!important; margin-bottom:-32767px!important; }
#footer     { clear:both; background: #aaa; padding:10px;height: 20px;}
* > #footer { position:relative; z-index:20; }    
</style>
```

Using this HTML Structure

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="col2"></div>
    </div>        
    <div id="col1"></div>        
    <div id="col3"></div>        
    <div id="footer"></div>    
</div>
```

Regards
Said

Comment: Either you don't understand the OP or my browser is broken.

Comment: I misunderstood/misread the question! and JS should resolve the problem