# firefox render order problem with div tag

Tags: javascript

I have a div tag which I populate dynamically.  The problem is that in Firefox when i do a test for size(height) I seem to need to run it twice in order to get the correct size.  This is the code:

```
alert("h = " + h + " height:" + document.getElementById("thumbDiv").clientHeight);
```

Ignore 'h' for the time being, what I am curious to know is what is the correct way to get the div tags height in firefox.  In ie I use offsetHeight which works for my purposes perfectly.  The other thing is the render order in firefox.  I populate the div and then query the height with .clientHeight and I get 102, which is I am assuming the empty height of the tag as I have set no height via style, if I press the button again I then get the height of the div with the enlcosed html page which I am pushing into the div.  Its odd, and slightly annoying.

I am trying to determine if there is enough room in the browser to display the div contents in their entireity, if not then I am disabling certain features otherwise I get into an infinite scroll problem...

Thanks, R.

Thanks R.

Comment: How and when are you pushing the content into the div? It sounds like you have a race condition, where you might measure the height of the div before its contents are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a javascript framework to do this for you.  Cross browser issues like this are rampant.  I recommend jQuery, but all the frameworks have their pro's and con's.

See:
[clientHeight/clientWidth returning different values on different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers)

For a similar Q&A.