# $(document).width() includes scrollbar in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have the following webpage:

A tall webpage with only a vertical scrollbar and no horizontal scrollbar. The document and window therefore have the same width.

When I ask IE8 for `$(document).width()`, it returns the viewport width including the vertical scrollbar. FF returns the right answer.

I cannot use `$('body')` for this, because it returns the same width as the window object (it is set to 100% somehow, so it doesn't work when the page gets smaller).

How can I make IE8 output the right value? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I actually did some more testing to my problem. and I found that when the horizontal scrollbar becomes visible as well (because of a smaller window), IE8 DOES get the right size. So this makes my problem even more complicated because I can't set an ugly `if(IE8)`-hack.

**UPDATE2**

The problem lies in my CSS and jQuery.
The actual case seems to be the problem:
My css says:

```
body
{
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

IE8 doesn't count this as part of the body, but IE7 does. How to fix this? Call jQuery for a fix?

Comment: did you try document.body.clientWidth

Comment: possible duplicate of [clientHeight/clientWidth returning different values on different browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers)

Comment: The answer of the above post is: use jQuery. Which is not solving my problem at the moment.

Comment: I added a ticket to jQuery. Hope they can fix this one for me.

Comment: So `$('body').width()` did seem to work after all...

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work when the contents spills over the body bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this problem to the jQuery crew: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8048.

They don't think it's a bug. Their advice is to use `$('body').width()`. And this does indeed the job for me.

I still find it strange that the body in IE8 is adjusted to the scrollbar, but the `$(document).width()` stays the same. I used this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28tsr/7/) for testing. It results in the same glitch, but jQuery thinks it's ok, because W3C doesn't say anything about it... Or something like that.