# can not get the width of the html element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create an element using js,and I have imported the related css,however I can not get the width of the element,this is the code:

css:

```
#mainDiv{
  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

js:

```
var mainDiv=document.createElement("div");
mainDiv.setAttribute("id","mainDiv");
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);

//now I want to get the width of the 'mainDiv'

var wd=mainDiv.style.width;
console.info(wd);
```

However the value of the 'wd' is always ''.

I wonder why?

Using the firebug,I found that the width of the 'mainDiv' is 500px.

But why I can not get the value in the js?

I do not want to set the width and height of the 'mainDiv' in the js like:

```
mainDiv.style.width='500px';
```

I want to set the size in the css.

Any idea?

Comment: This question is the poster child for why alot of people use frameworks such as jQuery. Browser handling of styles is so inconsitant that you need a crossbrowser framework to sort out the mess and get on with your goal.

Comment: we just use prototype1.4 now. I have not find any function can make it.

Comment: For the record, such code would only work if you assign the width "inline" or set it via code.. to get the actual width in pixels heximal gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var wd=mainDiv.clientWidth;
```

Comment: Great answer, but the cross browser inconsitency is a huge problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Use mainDiv.offsetWidth .

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Listen, this is an awful answer, but just use jQuery.

If you did this would be as simple as:

```
var width = $('#mainDiv').width(); // width has the value 500
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: What's not simple or so horrible in `mainDiv.clientWidth`?

Comment: @Shadow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers

Comment: good point, but what jQuery `.width()` returns in that case? As a side note, I really can't see any reason to start using jQuery just to get proper width of element.

Comment: @Shadow, the element width without padding, border or margin (according to the docs). And on your second point, true, but if you're doing anything client side I bet you could find a hundred uses for it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the actual width of a DOM element you must use offsetWidth.

From W3Schools:

> offsetWidth: Returns the width of an element, including borders and padding if any, but not margins

This example should work:

```
var mainDiv=document.createElement("div");
mainDiv.setAttribute("id","mainDiv");
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);

var wd=mainDiv.offsetWidth;
console.info(wd);
```

Comment: Because they in this case are correct, and you should credit sources instead of just copying.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get the width because you are trying to get it from the style. Sorry went into train, basically because you are not setting the style element but rather defining a class - JavaScript can't read the value from the element.

Answer (score -1):

It's because the element is not yet rendered. I know it's awful, but you should delay reading the width a bit:

```
var mainDiv=document.createElement("div");
mainDiv.setAttribute("id","mainDiv");
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
setTimeout(100, function() {
    console.info(mainDiv.style.width);
});
```