# What's the raw JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $(window).width

Tags: jquery, width

I've heard it's [offset.width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers/2334106#2334106), document.documentElement.clientWidth, and window.innerWidth

I'm curious for projects which I cannot use jQuery on, which solution I should use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function windowWidth() {
    var docElemProp = window.document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        body = window.document.body;
    return window.document.compatMode === "CSS1Compat" && docElemProp || body && body.clientWidth || docElemProp;
}
```

Taken (and modified slightly from the jQuery source:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/dimensions.js#L42

Answer (score 4):

[See](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.width) for yourself.
It uses different things. document.documentElement.clientWidth is among them.

It can also use  document.body.clientWidth

Answer (score 3):

This

```
window.innerWidth
```

The above property returns the same value as `$( window ).width()`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Jukh9/1/show/

However, IE8 does not implement this property...