# plain javascript to jquery - clientHeight

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script

```
(function(win){
    var doc = win.document;
    if (doc.querySelector && doc.addEventListener) {
        var toggler = doc.querySelector('.toggle-menu')
        var menu = doc.querySelector('.main-nav ul');
        menu.style.height = '0px';
        toggler.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (menu.style.height == '0px') {
                menu.style.height = 'auto';
                if (menu.clientHeight != 0) {
                    menu.style.height = menu.clientHeight+'px';
                }
            } else {
                menu.style.height = '0px';
            }
        });
    }
})(this);
```

What will be the jQuery version of that script, since i can't find a jQuery equivalent to clientHeight.

Comment: You can get similar results, but there is no exact equivalent of clientHeight in jQuery.  Why can't you mingle the two?  You could still use JS's clientHeight while using jQuery.

Comment: Right, I'm learning jQuery so thats why I asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`clientHeight` is not a jQuery property. It was introduced in Internet Explorer, but isn't part of the W3C specifications. It looks like it is only supported in Firefox and Internet Explorer. I've just tested that it works in the latest version of Chrome, though. Not sure if results are standard across browsers, though the link I posted below suggests no.

Also, Mozilla suggests the following formula to be used in place for browsers that don't support it:

> clientHeight can be calculated as CSS height + CSS padding - height of
>   horizontal scrollbar (if present).

I'm assuming that is the scrollbar of the element itself, not the entire browser window, unless the element takes up the entire window.

Sources:

- [clientHeight/clientWidth returning different values on different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight

Comment: I think that, even if "supported", it's safer to use these standard CSS attributes (height and padding).

Comment: Right, I definitively wouldn't rely on it if legacy browser support is desired.

Answer (score 2):

There is [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/). It will return the height of an element.

```
var menu = $('.main-nav ul');
....
menu.height()+'px';
```

Comment: Alexandra is already using .height in her script, so I assume she already knows about .height but is aware that it isn't the same.

Comment: @dweiss The question was and still is "to jQuery". The querySelector should replace the sizzle in jQuery - the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

As far as today - **September 2016**, I can see that jQuery (ver 3.1.0) still does not include its own method to get the `element.clientWidth` and `element.clientHeight` in a normalized way accross different browsers.

Nevertheless, investigating on different sources, it turns out **these JavaScript native properties are well supported** on the majority of browsers used today.
On the [MDN clientHeight article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) I can read it is supported on Chrome, Firefox (Gecko), Internet Explorer, Opera, Safari (WebKit), but no versioning is specified.

QuirksMode specifies [these properties are supported from IE 9+ and other browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport_desktop.html) when applied to the `window` and `document` objects.

In another QuirksMode article on the two properties applied to page elements, no specifications about browser support is given, but a very useful on-page tester is available to test by yourself element dimensions consistency on the browsers you have:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/elementdimensions.html

On [this article treating the clientHeight property](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcadejj.php) there is an important focus on differences between physical pixels and logical pixels on IE < 8 and IE >= 8:

> In Internet Explorer earlier than version 8, it retrieves the height
>   in physical pixel size, while from version 8, it returns the height in
>   logical pixel size.

Assuming that the use of the zoom on browsers is mainly used on mobile devices, I think it that:

- it is safe enough using `element.clientWidth` and `element.clientHeight` for desktop audience pages/web apps;
- for cross-device pages/web apps the usage of relative measure units (e.g. em's) could solve the gap between physical and logical pixels.

For an easier dimensions management, **em** unit could improve cross-platform development ([W3 org specs on units and rem's draft](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)), which seems to be [supported on modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem).
I still have no experience on relative measure units in CSS media-queries, but reading this [interesting article on the best unit measure for CSS media-queries](http://zellwk.com/blog/media-query-units/) perhaps it deserves a study.

Any opinion on these considerations is appreciated.