# <div> height not changing in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image in my HTML and i am trying to change its dimensions depending on the fact if it is portrait or landscape so that it doesn't cause much distortion. I have 3 buttons 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large' and each button changes height and width.

This is the if statement i have written yet but on clicking the button nothing happens

```
$('#large').click(function() {
var height = document.getElementById('#uploadedPhoto').clientHeight;
var width = document.getElementById('#uploadedPhoto').clientWidth;
    if (height > width) {
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('height', '95%');
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('width', '85%');    
    }
    else if (height < width) {
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('height', '85%');
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('width', '95%');
    }
    else {
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('height', '95%');
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('width', '95%');
        } 
});
```

This is the css of the uploadedImage /

```
#upoladedPhoto {
display:none;
position:relative;
cursor:move;
max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;
left: 5em;
opacity:0.75;
}
```

**The 3 buttons work when there is no if statement but in that case i only change the css property not taking in to consideration whether it is in potrait mode or landscape**

If there is a better method to attempt this then please share.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you have a typo (or misunderstanding) by including `#` in the `document.getElementById(..)`.

Comment: @Harry it isnt working even without #. Maybe it is because i havent defined the height and the width in CSS?

Comment: Is it possible to make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo mate?

Comment: add a fiddle for better understanding of problem.

Comment: lol there was a typo I was typing upoalded all this time instead of uploaded. Thanks though

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing `javascript` with `jquery`,

that will be

```
document.getElementById('uploadedPhoto').clientHeight;
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('#uploadedPhoto').clientHeight;
```

And I think there are some issues regarding `clientHeight` read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423759/plain-javascript-to-jquery-clientheight) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers).

You can use simple jquery

```
$('#uploadedPhoto').height();
```

Comment: still not working. I removed the #. Other two buttons without if statement are working perfectly but causing distortion

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('#uploadedPhoto')` is wrong

try

```
document.getElementById('uploadedPhoto')
```

You shouldn't include the `#` in the id passed to `document.getElementById`

Besides that, the `id` itself is different in the `$` function and in the `getElementById` function. It seems there was a typo which doesn't reflect in the `getElementById`, that's why the `if` is having trouble.

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/5Lewnwdp/) for your review.

Comment: still not working. I removed the #. Other two buttons without if statement are working perfectly but causing distortion.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
$('#large').click(function() {
$("img#upoladedPhoto").load(function() 
{
        var width = this.width;
        var height = this.height;
    if (height > width) {
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('height', '95%');
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('width', '85%');    
    }
    else if (height < width) {
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('height', '85%');
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('width', '95%');
    }
    else {
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('height', '95%');
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('width', '95%');
        } 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. Haven't tested it, but couldn't it just be a typo? When you're fetching the element by Id, you wrote `#uploadedPhoto`, but then, in the `if{}` statements you wrote `#upoladedPhoto`. See the difference? You're trying to apply some CSS to a non exisiting div ;-)