# IE: Unable to get value of the property 'clientWidth': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

The error message only show up on IE, but seems there is no solution to this issue.

I have already set `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` as `IE8`, but still cannot get it work.

What I am trying to do is use jQuery to reload the content of the table. But it seems the reloading by jQuery apparently cannot set the `clientWidth` because there is no counterpart of that term in jQuery.

```
<table style="" id="actionMap" class="top-table">
```

The id attribute of `<table>` is for DOM and class is for jQuery.

```
j(function() {
        j('#filter_workflows').change(function () {
            var workflow = j(this).val();
            var url = '<spring:url value="/actionMap" />' + '?filter_workflow=' + workflow;
            var savedWidth = document.getElementById("actionMap").clientWidth;
            j('table.top-table').load(url+' table.top-table > *');
            j('input[name=filter_workflow]').val(workflow);
            document.getElementById("actionMap").clientWidth = savedWidth;
        });
    });
```

Turns out the property `clientWidth` is read-only.

```
  document.getElementById("actionMap").clientWidth = savedWidth;
```

will never work out.

So how can we set the  clientWidth property after the jQuery reload the table?

Thanks

Comment: `$(window).width()` -- this normalizes the procedure in jQuery, as it accounts for box-models in different browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [clientHeight/clientWidth returning different values on different browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thank you but here I only want to set the clientWidth of the table. It seems after reloading jQuery never set that parameter so even we set the $(#actionMap).width() with something the clientWidth is still recognized as null by IE, then get script error.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

http://api.jquery.com/width/

clientWidth may-be client-specific (it can be that it's client-specific in a way that it's supported by everything except IE...)

jQuery has wrapper functions for these, see http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/offset/