# Getting an element's inner height

Tags: javascript, dom

How do you get an element's inner height, without padding and borders?

No jQuery, just pure JS, and a cross-browser solution (IE7 included)

[image]

Comment: Why not use `border-box` in css? That way you don't have to worry about these things... Then you can use `offsetHeight` which will return the proper height without the margin.

Comment: this is a very specific question for a plugin I make which has no CSS control, I just have to work with what I got

Comment: So...I guess you can still set the `box-sizing: border-box`, it'll save you some time and headaches.

Comment: I cannot, because my plugin runs on others' websites, which it is not up to me to change their CSS settings in any way that can harm the design

Comment: `element.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';`

Comment: Don't know what kind of plugin is it but I don't see why you shouldn't use it only on that element, I mean you're not changing any CSS other than what's necessary for your plugin to work.

Comment: yes, BUT this css setting is not for old IE, and also, there might be other code that works with the webpage that might mis-calculate things if I start changing CSS. this is ALWAYS a bad idea. never change, only work with what you have when it's not your own webpage

Comment: Maybe you could clone the element, change the `box-sizing`, then calculate that?

Comment: basically a good idea, BUT a very slow thing to do in my case, because i need it calculated on every scroll event. cloning will kill the performance of my plugin, which I am trying to improve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) - give the height *including* **padding** but without the 
**borders**.

[getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) - a way to tap into the CSS rules of an element and retrieve a property's value (padding)

Using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is a way to strip away units and leave only the numeric value (which is in *pixels*) 
`parseFloat` can also be used for more precise sub-pixel measurements

> Note that all values will automatically be converted by the DOM API to *pixels*

```js
function getInnerHeight( elm ){
  var computed = getComputedStyle(elm),
      padding = parseInt(computed.paddingTop) + parseInt(computed.paddingBottom);

  return elm.clientHeight - padding
}
```

## DEMO:

```js
// main method
function getInnerHeight( elm ){
  var computed = getComputedStyle(elm),
      padding = parseInt(computed.paddingTop) + parseInt(computed.paddingBottom);
  
  return elm.clientHeight - padding
}

// demo utility function
function printInnerHeight( selector ){
  console.clear()
  console.log(
    getInnerHeight( document.querySelector(selector) )
  )
}
```

```css
body{ display: flex; padding:0; margin: 0; }
div{ flex: 1; }

.demo1{
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 10px solid salmon;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.demo2{
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-bottom: 4vh;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 10px solid salmon;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  height: 150px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}


p::before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>inner height should be ~50px</h2>
  <button onclick="printInnerHeight('.demo1')">Get Inner Height</button>
  <p class='demo1'></p>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>inner height should be ~150px</h2>
  <button onclick="printInnerHeight('.demo2')">Get Inner Height</button>
  <p class='demo2'></p>
</div>
```

Comment: So, this words, but the `querySelector` should really be moved from `printInnerHeight` to `getInnerHeight`

Comment: @RegularJoe - it doesn't. `getInnerHeight` accepts an argument which is the element to detect height, and it should have no notion of any existing DOM elements, and not work with any given visible element

Answer (score 37):

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("Example"), null);
style.getPropertyValue("height");
```

The above version will work in modern browsers. Please check `currentStyle` for IE browsers.

Comment: you mean: `parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('height'));`

Comment: Internet Explorer will return "auto" if there is no height in the css http://jsfiddle.net/Kxsvx/ so you don't have the the height of it!

Comment: @Mic which Internet Explorer?

Comment: REMEMBER: If the `box-sizing` is set to `border-box`, you will still have to subtract the padding and border values.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT from comments:

http://jsfiddle.net/hTGCE/1/ (a bit more code then expected)

in the internet you find functions like this:

```
  function getRectangle(obj) {

          var r = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 0, height: 0 };

          if(!obj)
             return r;

          else if(typeof obj == "string")
             obj = document.getElementById(obj);


          if(typeof obj != "object")
             return r;

          if(typeof obj.offsetTop != "undefined") {

             r.height = parseInt(obj.offsetHeight);
             r.width  = parseInt(obj.offsetWidth);
             r.left = r.top = 0;

             while(obj && obj.tagName != "BODY") {

                r.top  += parseInt(obj.offsetTop);
                r.left += parseInt(obj.offsetLeft);

                obj = obj.offsetParent;
             }
          }
          return r;
       }
```

if you want to subtract the padding / border-width is set in the css-file and not dynamic in the style attribute:

```
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    var borderWidth = 0;

          try {
             borderWidth = getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue('border-top-width');

             } catch(e) {

             borderWidth = elem.currentStyle.borderWidth;
          } 
    borderWidth = parseInt(borderWidth.replace("px", ""), 10);
```

and with the padding the same. then you calculate it.

Comment: in the internet you can find all sort of rubbish code. I want THE ULTIMATE answer for this mystery, not a bloated, slow code..but thanks for the answer :)

Comment: if you have a dynamic height without a css attribute "height" for an element the method with "getComputedStyle" won't work. Or i am wrong?

Comment: ok. i thought the code with "getComputedStyle..." just read out the css attributes and doesn't calculate it if no "height" exists.

Comment: so i try it in a fiddle and IE is special again: if there is no height you get the value auto: http://jsfiddle.net/Kxsvx/

Comment: good detective work Mic! IE8 and below does show it's ugly face here. but there MUST be a more simple solution to this simple thing..

Comment: well, you can get the padding and borders and subtract it from the clientHeight of the element I guess.

Comment: maybe IE8 is gone in some years :D but be sure about the differences bitween the values of innerHeight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers i will edit this post to post a smaller code

Comment: This post is from like 3 years ago, and now i've checked and they are all the same

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `clientHeight` and `clientWidth` properties.

[MDN web doc for Element.clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) — clientWidth works exactly the same way.

Comment: This would include padding.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem and found out there is no native cross plattform solution but the solution is easy though

```
var actual_h = element.offsetHeight;

            if(parseInt(element.style.paddingTop.replace('px','')) > 0){
                actual_h=actual_h -  parseInt(element.style.paddingTop.replace('px',''));

            }
            if(parseInt(element.style.paddingBottom.replace('px','')) > 0){
                actual_h=actual_h -  parseInt(element.style.paddingBottom.replace('px',''));

            }
```

Comment: Be advised that, as MDN [states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Getting_style_information), "The `style` property is not useful for learning about the element's style in general, since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the element's inline `style` attribute [...]".