# Getting the style of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I want to get height of an element with JavaScript, but I want the value even if it is applied in a `<style>` tag, not just inline.

```
   <style>
     #test{height:100px;}
   </style>
   <div id="test"></div>
   <script>

   alert(document.getElementById("test").style.height);


   <script>
```

The above `alert` doesn't show anything because it just gets the inline style, not the entire style.  How can I get to access to all the styles of an element?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435604/get-element-inner-height
Guess this is the same question.

Comment: For start clear your markup. <div id="test"></div>

Answer (score 0):

if you want the full computed styles, use:

`window.getComputedStyles(document.querySelector('#test'));`

then go for:

```
window.getComputedStyles(document.querySelector('#test')).height;
```

This will give you the height in px, even if you specify a percentage height.

Also, you could use:

```
document.querySelector('#test').clientHeight;
```

This would include padding, though, depends what you need. Read more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight