# Get the height of an element minus padding, margin, border widths

Tags: javascript, css

Does anyone know if it's possible to get just the height of an element (minus vertical padding, border, and margin) when there is no inline height declaration? I need to support IE8 and above.

`el.style.height` doesn't work because the styles are set in an external style sheet.

`el.offsetHeight` or `el.clientHeight` doesn't work because they include more than just the element's height. And I can't just subtract the element's padding, etc. because those values are also set in a CSS stylesheet, and not inline (and so `el.style.paddingTop` doesn't work).

Also can't do `window.getComputedStyle(el)` because IE8 doesn't support this.

jQuery has the height() method, which offers this, but I'm not using jQuery in this project, plus I just want to know how to do this in pure JavaScript.

Anyone have any thoughts? Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned, jQuery achieves this somehow with .height(), so this must be possible somehow.

Comment: It probably uses `getComputedStyle`, and `currentStyle` for older IE.

Comment: Yup, jQuery's `height()` and `innerHeight()` both use `css()` internally, and `css()` uses `getComputedStyle` and `currentStyle` internally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get element inner height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435604/get-element-inner-height)

Comment: @adeneo I was unaware of currentStyle. I will try some combination of the 2 and post back if I find something that works. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr_Green Yep, I read that question, but I don't feel like it ever produced a full solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`element.getComputedStyle` would return the height according to the value of `box-sizing`. If the element is using `box-sizing: content-box;`, you can use `getComputedStyle` to compute the height without padding or borders:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("Example"), null);
style.getPropertyValue("height");
```

The above version will work in modern browsers. Please check currentStyle for IE browsers.

Cross browser:

```
try {
 el = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('example'), null)
     .getPropertyValue('height');
} catch(e) {
 el = document.getElementById('example').currentStyle.height;
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435604/get-element-inner-height)

Comment: `getElementById` can have only one argument.. what is this man? :)

Comment: also it's not necessary to use `try...catch` in this case, we can check for the existence of a member using `in` operator, such as by `if('getComputedStyle' in window) ... ` or use `typeof` such as `if(typeof window.getComputedStyle !== 'undefined')...`

Comment: One thing I'll add is that if the element's height is auto, `.currentStyle.height` will only return 'auto', and if its height is a percentage, it will only return that percentage, not the computed height in pixels. So in this case, if you still need to know the height of the element, you can take the `.offsetHeight` of it, then use `.currentStyle` to get any vertical padding or border values and subtract them from the offsetHeight value to give you the element's height. Though this wouldn't work if padding or borders were also set as percentages.

Comment: This won't work if you are using `box-sizing: border-box`, which is is the most common-sense to use.

Comment: This will not work if the style property of an element is not set

Comment: This contains padding, at least when I tried to use it on an SVG

Comment: im baffled why this was selected as the answer since it contains padding

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it returns the size including padding.

Comment: In contrast to [what Mr_Green wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197184/get-the-height-of-an-element-minus-padding-margin-border-widths#comment39239551_25197206), `getElementById` can actually have two arguments, the second being optional. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)
`var style = window.getComputedStyle(element [, pseudoElt]);`

Answer (score 118):

Here's the solution that works for both cases of `box-sizing`: `content-box` and `border-box`.

```
var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(element);

elementHeight = element.clientHeight;  // height with padding
elementWidth = element.clientWidth;   // width with padding

elementHeight -= parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingTop) + parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingBottom);
elementWidth -= parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingLeft) + parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingRight);
```

Works in IE9+

You can use feature detection

```
if (!getComputedStyle) { alert('Not supported'); }
```

**This will not work if element's `display` is `inline`. Use `inline-block` or use `getBoundingClientRect`.**

Answer (score 31):

Improved Dan's code to work on inline elements as well (using `offset*` instead of `client*`):

```
var cs = getComputedStyle(element);

var paddingX = parseFloat(cs.paddingLeft) + parseFloat(cs.paddingRight);
var paddingY = parseFloat(cs.paddingTop) + parseFloat(cs.paddingBottom);

var borderX = parseFloat(cs.borderLeftWidth) + parseFloat(cs.borderRightWidth);
var borderY = parseFloat(cs.borderTopWidth) + parseFloat(cs.borderBottomWidth);

// Element width and height minus padding and border
elementWidth = element.offsetWidth - paddingX - borderX;
elementHeight = element.offsetHeight - paddingY - borderY;
```

Comment: NOTE that offsetHeight include the size of the scrollBar too! so if the desired behavior is to not include the scrollBar that will not do. calculating the scroll width https://stackoverflow.com/a/13382873/7668448,

Answer (score 14):

Turned Dan's answer into a function

```
export const innerDimensions = (node) => {
  var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(node)

  let width = node.clientWidth // width with padding
  let height = node.clientHeight // height with padding

  height -= parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingTop) + parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingBottom)
  width -= parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingLeft) + parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingRight)
  return { height, width }
}
```

Comment: Very useful. To those utilizing this, I'd recommend using `node.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the precise decimal width and height of the element for more accuracy.

Answer (score -1):

Try element.currentStyle in `IE8`. But please remember, than `borderRightWidth` `(borderLeftWidth)` returns not pixels, but 'thin', 'medium', 'thick'.