# JS element offset width returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, containers, width

I try to get the width of an element but the returned value is wrong

```
   let container = document.querySelector('.content')
    console.log(container.offsetWidth) //this will log wrong value 1182px instead of 960px

  console.log(getComputedStyle(container).width) //1182px anyway I don't have any idea from where the value comes
```

[image]

I can not get an idea why the returned value is wrong

Comment: no it's not while the result is the same using computed

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29881817/965834s). Should work with `box-sizing: border-box`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This Worked for mebefore getting offset width you can set the width to

```
let container = document.querySelector('.content')
container.style.width = "fit-content";
console.log(container.offsetWidth);
```