# CSS grid - count number of columns (javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a CSS grid

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 12.5vw );
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 12.5vw );
  background-color: black;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  color: #444;
}


<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="box wide tall a">
 </div>
 <div class="box b">
 </div>
 <div class="box c">
 </div>
 <div class="box c">
 </div>
 <div class="box d">
 </div>
 <div class="box e">
 </div>
 <div class="box f">
 </div>
 <div class="box g">
 </div>
 <div class="box h">
 </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to know the number of columns in my javascript code. is it possible?

EDIT: the reason i want this is that if there is less than the good amount of items so that it makes a square, I want these extra items not to be displayed at all.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can add class to columns and use `document.querySelectorAll('.your_column_class').length`

Comment: So you want to know how many div childs you have?

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55243400/8620333

Comment: Thanks, this is for a mosaic gallery, I want to know how many columns I have in my responsive grid.
if there is less than the good amount of items so that it makes a perfect square, I want the last row to be hidden.

Answer (score 3):

You can use getElementsByClassName to retrieve all the box divs and get the array length:

```
var columns = document.getElementsByClassName('box').length
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the minmax part of the `grid-template-columns:`
eg `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr));`

with out it, you will always have 7 columns, and the grid columns wont be responsive and change as page width shrinks/expands.

can see Jen Simmons example page here : [Spice Gallery Layout](https://labs.jensimmons.com/2016/examples/spices-1.html)

A Solution that doesnt require any javascript.. but a few media queries..
is to wrap your .wrapper div with a container. and set a max height. per screen break point when every there would be un even images on the last row.
then set the .container overflow-y:hidden;

link to pen here : [Hide last row of grid with css](https://codepen.io/p4ttch/pen/qGgMYN?editors=1100)

Doing this with javascript you would need to know how many images you have, and what your minmax column widths are. vw units are basicaly width in %. so you would need to do some maths. with a mod function to know how many items are on the last row. and then need a way to hide them.