# How can I get an array of values or rows from my grid layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-grid

I'm trying to convert my CSS-grid into a CSV. I found this thread showing how to form the data if I can get it into an array format: [How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side).

Is there a way to select all of the div values in the grid table as an array? Or even better create an array of row arrays

```css
.grid-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-table">
  <div>head1</div>
  <div>head2</div>
  <div>head3</div>
  <div>head4</div>
  <div>head5</div>
  <div>item1</div>
  <div>item2</div>
  <div>item3</div>
  <div>item4</div>
  <div>item5</div>
  <div>item6</div>
  <div>item7</div>
  <div>item8</div>
  <div>item9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You state that this is a 'table', yet it's a set of `div` elements. If the output is actual tabular data, which makes sense if you want to export it to CSV, then use an actual `table` element. Are you expecting the rows/columns shown in the UI to be included as a 2D array in the output? Also, please show us what you've tried in order to solve this yourself.

Comment: Would it ok to add classes for heads and items ? Or at least could we know the number or columns in advance and assume that the n first divs are heads and the rest are items ?

Comment: yes the head elements do have a class but you can assume the first 5 are heads. I was thinking if I can get an array of all the values I can run it through a loop using mod 5 and form the rows that way

Comment: You can use [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/table) to get an 1D array of the values, then chunk it using [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8495687/519413) to get your 5xN 2D array. I'd still strongly suggest you use a `table` in your HTML for this though, as it makes far more sense in both terms of the UI and the JS to build the CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab all the items using `querySelectorAll` and use `getComputedStyle`
to count the number of columns in each row. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58393617/19584435)

```
var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.grid-table'))
var columnsCount = computedStyle.getPropertyValue("grid-template-columns").split(" ").length // in our case 5
```

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.grid-table')
var columns = getComputedStyle(container).getPropertyValue("grid-template-columns").split(" ").length;

var items = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-table div');

var output = []
var row = 0;

items.forEach(function (item, i) {
    if (i % columns === 0) {
        if (output.length > 0) {
            row++ ;
        }
            
        output.push([])
    } 
        
    output[row].push(item.innerHTML)
      
});

console.log(output)
```

```css
.grid-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-table">
<div>head1</div>
<div>head2</div>
<div>head3</div>
<div>head4</div>
<div>head5</div>
<div>item1</div>
<div>item2</div>
<div>item3</div>
<div>item4</div>
<div>item5</div>
<div>item6</div>
<div>item7</div>
<div>item8</div>
<div>item9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getGridArray(rows, columns){
    let gridLocations = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= rows; i++){
        for(let j = 1; j <= columns; j++){
            let position = {x:i, y:j};
            gridLocations.push(position);
        };
    };
    return gridLocations;
};
```

All you do is plug the number of rows and columns from your grid into this function. No variables needed. And since it returns an array it's easily chainable.