# My directive in angular not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm kinda new to angular.

I want to have a listener for whenever width of document changes.

So first of all I decided to add a $watch like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $window.innetWidth;
}, function(n, o){
    console.log(n);
    console.log(o);
});
```

But it only works on page load and not on resize.

Then I decided to write a Directive like this:

```
app.directive('watchWidth', [function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                element.style.display = 'none';

                $scope.$watch(function () {
                    return element.innerWidth;
                }, function (n,o) {
                    console.log(n);
                    console.log(o);
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

And add directive to my ng-view:

```
<div watchWidth ng-view class="main-wrapper"></div>
```

But nothing work and no error in console and I don't know what should I do!

Any help please?

Comment: Did you see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044338/window-resize-directive ?

Comment: try this: `clientWidth` instead of `innerWith`

Comment: or with jquery: `$(element).innerWidth()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435604/get-element-inner-height

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev clientWidth is undefined and still nothing to watch!
and I dont want to use jQuery in this project

Comment: @aSoler thank you. I was searching for two or three hours and this one missed.

Comment: @SinaMirhejazi did It worked? Happy to hear that! :)

Comment: change $window.innetWidth to $window.innerWidth;

Comment: replace to:`watch-width` in `<div watchWidth ng-view class="main-wrapper"></div>`

Comment: @SinaMirhejazi. if you can share your example we  help quicly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is my approach to resize the a specific element

```
.directive('resize', function (Ls) {
    return function (scope, element, attr) {
        scope.resizeWithOffset = function (offsetH) {
                return {
                    'min-height': (window.innerHeight - offsetH) + 'px',
                    'max-height': (window.innerHeight - offsetH) + 'px'
                };
        }
    }
})
```

In your html it would look like this

```
<ion-scroll ng-style="resizeWithOffset(270)" resize></ion-scroll>
```

Basically the element is now resizes down to window-height - the height u can specify ( in this case 270px)