# How do I get the number of items that will not fit inside the parent dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I currently have a draggable width container with some children.

[image: all_content_fit]

Since its width is draggable once the width is small enough that say for example only 3 elements can fit.
Expected outputs are (0), (1), and (+4) (Number of elements that overflow + 1).

[image: 3_overflow]

Other cases: Here only two elements fit, and 4 overflows.
The expected output is two circles with (0) and (+5).

[image: case3_only_2_Fit]

I saw other posts where they use a fixed width and calculate the number of elements that can fit from that. However, in my use case, the width is varying and I need to get the number of elements that can fit/overflow dynamically. How can this be done using javascript and plain CSS?

Comment: "Can this be done using react, javascript and plain css?" - the question you're asking really doesn't have anything to do with React.

Comment: Just use `getBoundingClientRect` to get the actual size of a container (or maybe `window.getComputedStyle`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435604/getting-an-elements-inner-height

Answer (score 0):

```
var popupDiv = document.getElementsById("container")
let count = Math.round(window.getComputedStyle(popupDiv).width/widthOFElement)
```

I hope this help. here the widthOFElement is the width of round element. and you can add this in dragabble event listener.