# $(document).width() versus document.body.clientWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there any differences between these two declarations? I want to use one of them to fix some css issues on the mobile version of a responsive site. Some of the tutorials suggest the `$(document).width()`, while others the `document.body.clientWidth`. I know that the first one is jquery, and the second is plain JavaScript, but are there any differences besides that? Which one is better to use?

I'd like to use them this way:

```
if ($(document).width() < 768) { ... }
```

or

```
if (document.body.clientWidth < 768) { ... }
```

Comment: They should return the exact same value, so which one you use is up to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers

Comment: The main difference is that the first is written with a help of jQuery, whilst the second is in plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are different. jQuery does a bunch of things to try to normalize the results.

See [the source code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=width):

```
if (elem.nodeType === 9) {
    doc = elem.documentElement;

    // Either scroll[Width/Height] or offset[Width/Height] or client[Width/Height], whichever is greatest
    // unfortunately, this causes bug #3838 in IE6/8 only, but there is currently no good, small way to fix it.
    return Math.max(
    elem.body["scroll" + name], doc["scroll" + name], elem.body["offset" + name], doc["offset" + name], doc["client" + name]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

document.body.clientWidth = $(document).width() + (left padding + right padding)