# Preview and zoom image like Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

When you open an image in Firefox, it has the following characteristics:

- Displayed centered in the browser.
- Will have a height/width contained (does not exceed browser dimensions).
- Does not resize larger than its max size.
- Does not resize at all if its smaller than the browser window.
- Retains aspect ratio.
- Has a zoom tool which resizes the image to its max size and allows it to exceed browser dimensions.

How would I replicate this using CSS/JS? I've tried several different methods using CSS but I'm assuming it requires JS and I can't find any examples.

The best results I've achieved using contain:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-url: {location of image}
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
```

But this only produces nice results with larger images, as it stretches smaller images to the match the browser height or width whereby instead I want images smaller than the browser to just be centered and retain their max height/width.

Comment: In Firefox the image is rendered as an img element. Do you need to have it as background or is an img element also okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/bafiqi/9/)***

<sup>(Disclaimer: Modern browsers only: (IE9+))</sup>

all you need is:

```
<div id="parent">
  <img src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/aSqDLP0.png);
}

body{ /* or use a wrapper element instead */
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#parent{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#parent img{
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px #111;
}
```

**The above is enough for the centering and resize stuff.**
If you want to additionally do exactly like Firefox does:

- **zoom-in cursor** on hover - if image is resized by the browser (small)
- **scroll the window to the clicked coordinates** - if image is small
- **zoom-out cursor** - if image is zoomed (clicked) - show the `-`

than a bit of jQuery might come handy:

```
var $parent = $("#parent"),
    isParentSmaller = false,
    zoom = false,
    parW, parH,
    imgW, imgH;

$parent.find("img").on("mouseenter click", function( e ){

  imgW = this.naturalWidth;
  imgH = this.naturalHeight;
  parW = $parent.width();
  parH = $parent.height();
  isParentSmaller = parW-1 < imgW || parH-1 < imgH;

  $(this).css({
    cursor: isParentSmaller ? (zoom?"zoom-out":"zoom-in") : "auto"
  });

  if(e.type=="click" && isParentSmaller){
    zoom = !zoom;       // Toggle zoom boolean  
    $(this).css({       // Apply cursor styles
      maxWidth  : zoom ? "none" : "100vw",
      maxHeight : zoom ? "none" : "100vh",
      cursor    : zoom ? "zoom-out":"zoom-in"
    });
    // Scroll window where we want to zoom:
    window.scrollTo(((imgW/parW)-1)*e.clientX, ((imgH/parH)-1)*e.clientY);
  }

});
```

Modesty time, the above performs even better than Firefox, since Firefox looses the Magnifying glass cursor if you resize the window :)

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I re-wrote my answer because my previous solution wouldn't work in Firefox (oh, the irony). Also it caused strange behaviours in other browsers. Reason was flexbox to center the image both vertically and horizontally.*

Let's do this step by step.

For keeping the aspect ratio of an image while setting maximum dimensions can be achieved with this:

```
.img {
  display: block; // could also be inline-block or other block-like types
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

Now, centering an element both vertically and horizontally are technically 3 lines of code with flexbox. As mentioned above, this caused strange behaviours when scaling the images in some browsers. Instead we use `text-align: center` to center the image along the x-axis and a method with something called a "Ghost Element" to center the image along the y-axis. You can learn more about it in [this article from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/). In summary, we have this to center the element:

```
.parent {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.parent:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}

.centered-child {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

At last, we combine the scaling and centering. I assume the HTML only exists of a single `<img class="img" ...>` in the body.

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: -0.25em;
}

.img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

### Now we implement the zooming

In order to zoom the image we need JavaScript. Let's use jQuery.

It's not nice to change css attributes in JavaScript, so we prepare two extra classes.

```
.img.is-zoomable {
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

.img.is-zoomed {
  cursor: zoom-out;
  max-height: none;
  max-width: none;
}
```

On click JavaScript will toggle the class `is-zoomed` and on mouseenter we decide if the image can be zoomed. If it can be zoomed, we add the class `is-zoomable`.

```
$('.img').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('is-zoomed');
});
$('.img').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var origWidth = this.naturalWidth;
    var origHeight = this.naturalHeight;
    var currWidth = $(this).width();
    var currHeight = $(this).height();
    if (origWidth !== currWidth || origHeight !== currHeight) {
        $(this).addClass('is-zoomable');
    }
});
```

Et voilà, we're done. See [my codepen](http://codepen.io/timomeh/pen/pJPqxa/) for a working example.

Comment: @TimoM your example is buggy http://jsbin.com/dehalo/2/edit?html,css,js,output - Click  the image *and see it happen*. Am I missing something?

Comment: What are those variables `$(this).clientWidth` that return `undefined` ?  Also I'd suggest to just take a quick look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It seems to be buggy in the tiny jsbin iframe. It works well in every browser with every viewport size. Here's [MDN about `clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth). I like to use this instead of `naturalWidth` (and -height) because it's not related specific to an HTMLImageElement. Since the box-model of an image won't differ in other browsers, it's no problem to use it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If it should also work in the iframe, simply set the `content` of the Ghost Element to none when zoomed. But I'm not going to add unnecessary and confusing code for this edge-case.

Comment: @TimoM you should `console.log` than your variable `origWidth` cause it returns `undefined`! Your demo is broken even if downloaded from jsBin, so it's not about jsBin frame but about your code (Chrome browser) cause even in jsFiddle there's the same bug on zoom. (Also a minor concern is the magnifying glass that appears even if we cannot operate with the zoom...) any ideas?

Comment: @TimoM I think that instead of `$(this).clientWidth` you wanted to use `this.clientWidth` but in any case that's not the value you need cause **it'll not return the original image width**.

Comment: You're right, `this.clientWidth` is correct because it's a normal DOM value. This solved the undefined and the magnifying glass thing, too.

Comment: @TimoM :) ok,  but still please see this demo: http://jsbin.com/dehalo/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output hover and see in console: `clientWidth` and jQ's `.width()` do the same role. If you wanted to get the really original image width you've could done it preloading your image using `var img = new Image()` and that assigning the src and on `img.onload` fn get the `this.width` and `this.height` and store that inside variables. ...or simply use the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` (IE9+)

Comment: I changed it to `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`, just to be sure. It works for me, but I'm at the moment simply too tired to test this every time in all browsers. Is it ok for you now?

Comment: @TimoM Apparently better! well done! Just, the demo is better now but still some issues when the height is really small and with the cursors... and the missing scroll-to-point... I'd also like to create something that is at least IE8 compatible but I'm also too tired... :( see you around! Happy coding

Comment: For me it works in Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox nice with every viewport size. I assume this has something to do with JSBin's iframe. But, as I said, fixing this to support this edge-case just needs to set the `content` of `body:before` to `none`. I don't want to confuse people with my answer by supporting viewing this in JSBin, so I won't implement this.

Comment: @TimoM PS: I understand, just I was not talking about JSBin or any online editor, if you recreate your whole code inside a blank document the issues are the same :)

Comment: I created this whole thing right from the start in a blank document, tested it and copied it over here and on codepen :) And it only shows the zoom-cursor if it can be zoomed; it is nice scaled and centered everywhere; it can be zoomed without glichting all over the place like in your JSBin. Please, don't assume stuff and stop being subliminal rude.

Comment: I could simply comment on your (accepted) version, that this is not nice frontend code at all, because *it is not nice front end code at all*. You're setting css attributes in JavaScript, a total no-go. You use id's in your css, a total no-go. Your whole JavaScript Code is running everytime on click AND mouseenter. But I'm not going to comment on your solution that it's a piece of crap. Instead I came with an other, better, more simple and clear approach (which admittedly won't work every time because of the `clientWidth`-blunder, but we're over that, right?).

Comment: You guys have to feel a bit of responsibility when posting answers on SO. Teaching someone to use IDs in CSS and change CSS in jQuery with `$.css()` will cause them to actually **think this is good.** And they will use these wrong methods over and over again. Just because something works doesn't mean it's good, especially in front end dev.