# clientHeight IE vs Chrome with fixed footer

Tags: internet-explorer, footer, fixed, ui-select

in an application I want a fixed footer (a div that stays in front of everything, not a sticky footer at the bottom of the page) with a scrollable div above. With the following code everything is working fine:

```
<style>
.page{
   position:absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0px;
   overflow:auto; 
}
.footer{
   position:fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 40px;
   background-color:blue;
   width:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="page"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

except that dropdowns created with ui-select will show dropdowns behind the footer... The ui-select component is able of automaticly position the drowpdown upwards if theres no space below the dropwdown. The check works with:
document.documentElement.clientHeight
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)

While searching I came acroos these sites.

[clientHeight/clientWidth returning different values on different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

Regarding the Internet Explorer model bug (I'm not sure if the height is affected too), the border is included in the clientHeight but the margin isn't. That's the reason I added the margin-bottom: 40px; to the the html tag...

```
html{
   margin-bottom:40px;
    }
```

...to substract 40 from the clientHeight. That's working fine except for the Internet Explorer (the main target browser :( )

I created a test to show the different behavior (I've also read that only inside the resize event of the IE the value is calculated correct, so I used a resize listener to print the clientHeght.... You have to copy/paste the code to a local html file to test it:

https://jsfiddle.net/93rvoftk/

Results:
[image: Results]

As you can see, the clientHeight isn't calculated correctly.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a chance to bring the internet exploder (that's how we call it) to calculate the correct value?
2. Do you have any other idea to prevent the dropdown list from showing up behind the footer? Changing ui-selects code isn't an option.
3. Do you have any other idea to implement a sticky footer (a div that sticks to the window bottom like a toolbar, not to the end of a page like a sticky footer) regarding the problem of the overlapping of elements and drop down lists of ui-select?

Thank you so much in advance, I searched the whole day for a solution...

Kind regards

moe

Comment: 2. A higher z-index for the dropdown elements should at least make sure the content is visible above the footer.

Comment: I tried that without success. Maybe the position: fixed ignores the z-index? I will try it again after reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Understanding_CSS_z-index%2FThe_stacking_context

Comment: Could you show me how you would solve it with z-index? I tried several combination of position: fixed and absoulute and z-indexes but the dropdown won't be pushed to the front...

Comment: Have a working example? [mcve]