# document.documentElement.clientWidth - returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I try to read the current window width. It is currently set to 768 in chrome developer tools.

[image]

But if I call `document.documentElement.clientWidth` in the console, then I get `758`.

---

Answer to Suggested Answer: No, jquery does not solve it either. If I call `$(window).width();` then I also get 758. And if I call `$(document).width();` I get 992

Comment: Does this answer your question? [clientHeight/clientWidth returning different values on different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833699/clientheight-clientwidth-returning-different-values-on-different-browsers)

Comment: No, jquery does not solve it either. If I call `$(window).width()` then I also get 758. And if I call `$(document).width();` I get 992

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDN [states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) that

> The Element.clientWidth property is zero for inline elements and elements with no CSS; otherwise, it's the inner width of an element in pixels. It includes padding but excludes borders, margins, and **vertical scrollbars** (if present).

and I see a scrollbar on your screenshot. Maybe that is the reason?

Comment: You are right! I have a scrollbar which is exactly 10px wide, this is indeed the reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Curveball pointed me to the right direction. I am indeed using a custom scrollbar with a width of 10px which is substracted when calling `document.documentElement.clientWidth`.

```
/* Scrollbar */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
  }
```

I solved it by using:

```
window.innerWidth;    // output: 768
```